# Can browserify require a vinyl file generated in gulp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browserify, commonjs

I've just started using `gulp` and `browserify` and I need some help with this problem:

I'm using a lib called `ng-autobootstrap` to generate a browserify compatible file, which is later on required in the main script. Here's my `autobootstrap` task:

```
gulp.task "autobootstrap", ->
  gulp.src("source/**/*.{coffee,js}",
    read: false
    base: "source"
  )
  .pipe(ngAutoBootstrap(
    moduleTypes:
      animation:
        path: "**/animations/*.{coffee,js}",
      constant:
        path: "**/constants/*.{coffee,js}",
      controller:
        path: "**/controllers/*.{coffee,js}",
      directive:
        path: "**/directives/*.{coffee,js}",
      factory:
        path: "**/factories/*.{coffee,js}",
      filter:
        path: "**/filters/*.{coffee,js}",
      provider:
        path: "**/providers/*.{coffee,js}",
      service:
        path: "**/services/*.{coffee,js}",
      value:
        path: "**/values/*.{coffee,js}",
      # config modules are pulled in like this:
      # app.config(require("./path/to-config"))
      config:
        path: "**/*-config.{coffee,js}"
  ))
```

If I add `.pipe(gulp.dest("./source/"))`, it will create a `bootstrap.js` file in the `source` directory, but this is not exactly what I want, I would rather keep that directory clean. As far as I understand, up to now I have a vinyl file in memory, with the following content:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
    // Controllers
    app.controller('AppController', require('./controllers/app-controller'));
    app.controller('UsersController', require('./controllers/users-controller'));
    // ... and so on
};
```

Let's suppose the `source/js/main.js` file looks like this:

```
app = angular.module("app");
require("./bootstrap")(app); // this is the file generated by ng-autobootstrap
```

And a simple `browserify` task which creates the `build/bundle.js` file:

```
browserify = require('browserify')
gulp = require('gulp')
source = require('vinyl-source-stream')

gulp.task 'browserify', ->
  browserify('./source/main.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
```

Now, if I modify the `autobootstrap` to write the file to disc first, then run `browserify`, this is all fine, the `./bootstrap` file will be there. But is there a way to avoid writing to disc? Something like adding a vinyl file to `browserify`'s search tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`b.require`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify#brequirefile-opts) to make a file available from outside of the bundle. And in order to use the vinyl streams, that Gulp uses/emits, with Browserify; we make a small inline transform using [`through2.obj`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) to emit only the contents.

A note on using `b.require` is that you need to [`b.exclude`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify#bexcludefile) so that `module-deps` doesn't try to resolve it in the `node_modules` directories, etc. *See issues [#908](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/908#issuecomment-74909062) and [#1106](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1106) for more information.*

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through = require('through2');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify-bundle', function() {
    return browserify('./test/main.js')
        // We need to exclude the required module so `module-deps` doesn't try to resolve it in the `node_modules` directories, etc
        // Suggested here: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/908#issuecomment-74909062
        //      See also: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1106
        .exclude('some-func')
        // Then add in the module to the bundle
        .require(
            gulp.src('./test/hidden-some-func.js')
                // Any plugins here....
                // .pipe(ngAutoBootstrap(..)
                //
                // Then convert it to a object stream with only the `contents` for browserify to consume
                .pipe(through.obj(function(chunk, env, cb) {
                    if (chunk.isStream()) {
                        self.emit('error', new gutil.PluginError(PLUGIN_NAME, 'Cannot operate on stream'));
                    }
                    else if (chunk.isBuffer()) {
                        this.push(chunk.contents);
                    }

                    // "call callback when the transform operation is complete."
                    cb();
                })),
            {
                // Dependency name to inject
                expose: 'some-func',
                // So that relative requires will be resolvable
                basedir: './test/'
            }
        )
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Comment: Seems to be the answer I was looking for, but I gave up on using browserify, and therefore I cannot test it. But I mark this as the correct answer :-) Thank you!